# Batch - copy folders based on last 2 characters

Tags: batch-file

I've searched the web and can not find solution or I can not adapt them to my problem. 
I would like for batch to copy subfolders from folder TEMP (few thousand subfolders) only if last two characters of any subfolder are 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /d %%f in ("%temp%\*14") do (
    md "c:\somewhere\%%~nxf" > nul 2>nul 
    xcopy "%%~ff" "c:\somewhere\%%~nxf" /e /y
)
```

Comment: It's working. Thank you so much. Is it possible to add line to copy only files with names MATIKGL.dbf and PROMGL.dbf from each folder that is going to be copied into new created (not all files). Every subfolder in TEMP have those two files (among others).

Comment: @JovicaBozic, inside the for loop replace xcopy line with `xcopy "%%~ff\matikgl.dbf" "c:\somewhere\%%~nxf" /e /y`, and add a equivalent the line for the second file.

Answer (score 0):

For *directory* names you need some string ops;

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /d %%d in (c:\temp\*.*) do (
    set path=%%d

    if !path:~-2! equ 14 (
        echo directory is: %%d
        rem copy %%d .... etc
    )
)
```