# Copy folder to location based on 8 last character of the folder

Tags: batch-file

I have tried to modify this script but with no joy: [The original script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22069673/batch-copy-folders-based-on-last-2-characters)

```
ECHO ON
for /d %%f in ("\*test-123") do (
     xcopy "%%~ff" "\\192.168.1.10\test folder\=== test folder====\%%~nxf" /e /y
)
pause
```

From what I understand. The above code should do the following. (Note, I have made change to try to achieve this)

1. Identify all the folder that have `test-123` at the end of it e.g. `My Folder - Test-123`
2. Copy those folders to `\\192.168.1.10\test folder\=== test folder====\%%~nxf`

I have tried for the last 5 hours but not joy, am I missing something.

The solution:

```
ECHO ON
for /d %%f in ("%c:\test%\*test-123") do (
     robocopy "%%~ff" "c:\test\test\test\%%~nxf" /MIR /R:1 /W:1
)
pause
```

Comment: Not sure how much difference it makes, but note that your linked question does an `md`, which creates the target directory if it doesn't already exist. You don't seem to be doing that. Incidentally, `test-123` is 8 characters, but that's just being picky.

Comment: @icabod You are not being picky, you are being correct, which is a goodthing. I am trying it out. bare with me.

Comment: @Mofi - Of course, done.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
ECHO ON
for /d %%f in ("%c:\test%\*test-123") do (
     robocopy "%%~ff" "c:\test\test\test\%%~nxf" /MIR /R:1 /W:1
)
pause
```

Please note, UNC paths do not work